# Customizing the from field in the mail sent from php mail function

Tags: php, sendmail

Im using the following code to send mail from my php script running on my ubuntu server.

```
$to = "<receipients_email_id_here>";
$subject = "Hello";
$txt = "<Message Body>";
$headers = "From: Site Name <jims@mysite.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

if(mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers)){
    print "Sent";
}
else
{
    print "Failed";
}
```

When user receives the mail he sees **`"Site Name <jims@mysite.com>"`** in the from field. I would like the from field to **just show "Site Name"** and also i want to add a **hyperlink** to it to point to my website. 
Is this possible to do from the php code ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the settings on the receiver's client software.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Ahmad Hajjar and I think hiperlink it's not possible or spammers will love it!